# Combining set with set operators

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When working with set operators (UNION, UNION ALL, INTERSECT, EXCEPT), I realized that :

- they use distinctness-based comparison and not equality based.
- Because these operators are set operators and not cursor operators,
  the individual queries are not allowed to have ORDER BY clauses.

I want to understand these two points.

Comment: 1) NULL is treated differently. 2) Not needed, no purpose.

Comment: I'm quite unclear on your question.  Those points seem quite clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to understand what is distinctness-based comparison? and what is set and cursor operators?

Comment: Distinct grouping and equality use the same logic in T-SQL, with the sole difference that `NULL` values are grouped together, but do not compare equal. The second point is unnecessarily obtuse: `ORDER BY` is not allowed except on the outer part of the query because it doesn't make any logical sense to add an order to a set when used in a set-based operation (combining two sets yields the same set regardless of how we consider them ordered). There is no need to mention cursors there at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - the above points are doubtless from Itzik Ben Gan who will have defined exactly what he means by cursor earlier in the text (not a TSQL cursor as here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxgc4.png) .